# Help with Probability

Tags: probability

Hey Im a new guy here and need some help.

I have an assignment bugging me. I can't really figure out which why to go around it.
I'm thinking conditional probaility but how to apply the Bayes Theorem is unclear to me in this situation.

We have a company that does 40 researches on treatment day 1 (X1) and 40 on day 2 (X2). The probability of a succes is 0,6  Y=X1+X2

3. Calculate the probability so there are 20 successes on the first day and 20 successes on the second day.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please explain "The probability of a succes is 0,6 Y=X1+X2".

Comment: The probability of a success is 60 pct and Y is a stochastic variable of the total successes over the two days.
Can you give me an idea on how to proceed?

Comment: Are you familiar with **Binomial Distributions**?  Because you have two *independent and identically* binomial distributed random variables.  Also, do you want the probability of exactly 20, or at least 20 successes?

Comment: as i understand from the question in the book its exactly 20. Yes im familiar with it but unsure how to use it in this problem

Answer (score 1):

It is reasonable to assume that trials conducted on different days are independent (researchers take efforts to ensure this).   So what you have is two *independent and identically* **binomial distributed** random variables.

$$X_\ast \sim {\cal Bin}(40, 0.60) \iff \mathsf P(X_\ast = k) = \dbinom{40}{k} 0.60^k \,0.40^{(40-k)} \operatorname{\bf 1}_{\{0\ldots 40\}}(k)$$

Since the trials are independent, conditional probability is not involved. nbsp; Just use the **product rule** for the probability of the intersection of independent events.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X_1=20, X_2=20) & = \mathsf P(X_1=20)\mathsf P(X_2=20)
\\[2ex] & =  \ldots
\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?